# Google Map Swift SDK - how to combine fitbounds and center user location?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, location, google-maps-sdk-ios

What I'm attempting to do is run fitbounds on a set of markers, which works perfectly. However, I would like to center the map based on the user's location while keeping all markers within the map view. But I haven't found a solution. Is it possible? below is my code currently use to fit bounds.

```
 func focusMapToShowAllMarkers() {
    
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    for location in locationsArray
    {
        let latitude = location.position.latitude
        let longitude = location.position.longitude

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude)
        //marker.map = self.viewMap
        
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    }
    //bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude))

    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 10)
  
    
    viewMap.animate(with:update)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my solution:

```
func calculateMapFitBounds(
  userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
  contents: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
) -> GMSCoordinateBounds {
  //SW
  var minLat = userLocation.latitude
  var minLng = userLocation.longitude

  //NE
  var maxLat = userLocation.latitude
  var maxLng = userLocation.longitude

  for content in contents {
    // Populating Top left cordinate (SW)
    minLat = min(minLat, content.latitude)
    minLng = min(minLng, content.longitude)

    // Populating Bottom right cordinate (NE)
    maxLng = max(maxLng, content.longitude)
    maxLat = max(maxLat, content.latitude)
  }

  // Calculating Delta fit bounds
  let latDelta = max(abs(userLocation.latitude - minLat), abs(maxLat - userLocation.latitude))
  let lngDelta = max(abs(userLocation.longitude - maxLng), abs(minLng - userLocation.longitude))

  // Calculating SW
  minLat = userLocation.latitude - latDelta
  minLng = userLocation.longitude - lngDelta

  let swLatLng = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: minLat, longitude: minLng)

  maxLat = userLocation.latitude + latDelta
  maxLng = userLocation.longitude + lngDelta

  let latlngBounds = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: maxLat, longitude: maxLng)

  return GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: swLatLng, coordinate: latlngBounds)
}
```

Then use it for your map:

```
let bounds = calculateMapFitBounds(...)
mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: padding))
```